# Fetch all Enum constants

Tags: java, enums

How to retrieve all values of enums at once?
**Expected Values :** ["Male", "Female"]
**Output of *GenderEnum.values()* :** ["MALE", "FEMALE"]

```
    public enum SPGenderEnum {
        MALE("Male"),
        FEMALE("Female");

        private SPGenderEnum(final String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        private final String type;

        public String getType() {return type;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Iterate over `.values()` and on each item call `.toString()` in this case... Btw you should to call that overriden method `toString` as `getType()`, its more clear, but I guess getType will be probably reserved :D

Comment: Can you be clear with your question ?

Comment: Folks, he is a newcomer. Let's not demotivate by downvoting. Let's see if he can edit the question properly

Comment: Thanks for downvoting!! Could you please let me know what am I missing here? I'll surely provide all details.

Comment: What do you mean, "retrieve"? Into what? A list, an array, a String?

Comment: Basically I don't want to iterate over enums. Just like we have all values of enum retrieved by just calling *.values()*. I was wondering if there is anything available to retrieve **["Male", "Female"]** instead of **["MALE", "FEMALE"]**.

Comment: @daniu I guess the format doesn't matter here. I just need all the values at once like **["Male", "Female"]** and not **["MALE", "FEMALE"]**

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Java 8, the streams API is probably the easiest way to retrieve the values you want:

```
Stream.of(GenderEnum.values())       // create stream of enum constants
      .map(e -> e.getType())         // for each constant, retrieve getType()
      .collect(Collectors.toList())  // collect results into a list
```

The expression `e -> e.getType()` is called a *lambda expression*, and it is a short-hand way of declaring a very simple function.  The `map` operator applies that function to every element in the stream, replacing each element with the function's return value.  In this case, the lambda returns the result of calling `e.getType()`, where `e` is assumed to be a `GenderEnum` value.

Simple lambdas like this one could be rewritten in a more concise form called a *method reference*, as in @ifly6's answer.

You could collect the results into a `String[]` instead by replacing `collect(Collectors.toList())` with `toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 3):

Seemingly, you want your enums as a list of strings? That seemingly is what you expect from the constructor call. However it is, if you want that, I would use something like this:

```
Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values())  // prefer Arrays#stream to Stream#of due to 
                                  // lazy loading and primitive type handling
    .map(YourEnum::toString)      // prefer method reference to lambda
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // prefer lists to arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need the `type` string only for representational purposes you could as well overwrite the enum's toString method to return the capitalized version of the value.

```
public enum SPGenderEnum {

    MALE, FEMALE;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
        // call toString of supertype
        String name =  super.toString();
        // capitalize the uppercase enum value
        return name.substring(0,1) + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

or define the enum values differently in the first place:

```
public enum SPGenderEnum {

    Male, Female;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want, it should also works with call `toString()` in your case

```
    SPGenderEnum[]  values = SPGenderEnum.values();

    //to print eg.
    for (SPGenderEnum spgItem : values) {
        System.out.println(spgItem.getType());
    }

    //to store in String array
    String[] strVals = new String[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strVals.length; i++) {
        strVals[i]= values[i].getType();
    }
```

Comment: This would just print it out. It wouldn't return some object holding what he wants.

Comment: @ifly6 to keep your mind calm, I edited my post how to store it in the String array, thanks for pointing ;)